# CSS animation of a pulsing circle

Tags: css, animation

i need help creating pulsing circle thing inside this animation, i've come pretty close with the rest of it i think, also any other help with the code is appreciated!
Gradient thing i tried didnt make it pulse but i think the color is good.

[Animation i have to make](https://giphy.com/gifs/RybwWJlLT7r8syjYoF)

[My code so far](https://codepen.io/Central-Attack/pen/XWGyYar)

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #050210;
}

.circle {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(#fb5dad, #55fb9f, #b97aff);
    animation: my-animation 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes my-animation {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.circle span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(#fb5dad, #55fb9f, #b97aff);
    animation-name: my-animation;
    animation-duration: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.circle span:nth-child(1) {
    filter: blur(5px);

}

.circle span:nth-child(2) {
    filter: blur(10px);
}

.circle span:nth-child(3) {
    filter: blur(25px);
}

.circle span:nth-child(4) {
    filter: blur(50px);
}

.circle::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    background: radial-gradient(black, rgb(11, 11, 88));
    border-radius: 50%;


}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Tried doing things with 2d transformation scale gradient but to no success.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Just the "pulsing" effect? I'm not seeing a pulse in your GIF - the pulsing is an illusion caused by the rotation I think. Otherwise I would agree this already looks pretty good.

Comment: My assignment just got accepted as is, guess that pulsing is an illusion...thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that your assignment got accepted but i still wanted to showcase the solution.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #050210;
}

.circle {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(#fb5dad, #55fb9f, #b97aff);
    animation: my-animation 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes my-animation {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.circle span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(#fb5dad, #55fb9f, #b97aff);
    animation-name: my-animation;
    animation-duration: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.circle span:nth-child(1) {
    filter: blur(5px);

}

.circle span:nth-child(2) {
    filter: blur(10px);
}

.circle span:nth-child(3) {
    filter: blur(25px);
}

.circle span:nth-child(4) {
    filter: blur(50px);
}

.circle::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    background: radial-gradient(black, rgb(11, 11, 88));
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.pulse {
  background: rgba(11, 11, 88, .4);
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: 1s pulse infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    scale: 0;
    background: rgba(11, 11, 88, .4);
  }
  100% {
    scale: 1;
    background: rgba(11, 11, 88, .0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      <div class="pulse"></div>
    </div>
```